# Is there any public protocol standard for such requests browser sends to the os?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, operating-system

I have an idea to restrict the selection of files in the selection window that are larger than the specified file size from being selected.

And all results I have searched like this code which only can do this **in the browser**.

```js
const maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10MB

fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  if (file.size > maxSize) {
    alert('Error: File is too large. Please choose a file less than 10MB.');
  }
  // ...
});
```

However, I find a cool attribute called *accept*.

The *accept* attribute of the input tag in the html tag controls the client's selection window.
For example, I can use the follow code allows you to only select jpg files **in the selection window.**

```js
<input type="file" accept=".jpg" />
```

I searched for the implementation principle and got the result that the browser sends a **request** to os.
But when I continue to search the request implementation, I got nothing.

Is there a similar browser api that can do this, affecting the client's (os) selection window, and is there a public protocol standard for such requests?

Comment: No, `accept` is only about file type, and you can't really trust it anyway. And `accept` is also only "in the browser" because it's an HTML attribute. What's wrong with the solution you already have?

Comment: @Pointy I want to improve the user experience, accept can affected the select dialog(I use mac os and finder, so it is the finder window) directly, but use the above solution you still can choose that file. Why I can not trust accept, you mean the compatibility? I do not care.  Because it's my project and I'm the only one using it

Comment: People can spoof `accept` in various ways, but yea if you don't plan on tricking yourself that's probably not an issue.

Comment: @Pointy actually I wonder why `accept` so special? Is there no more attribute like this can affected the os so brutally? why browser does not provide such hint api, for secure?

Comment: Note that `accept` itself is fairly recent. 10 years ago there was no such thing. It takes a while to get standards like that introduced; recall that browsers run on all sorts of platforms, and a standard isn't really worth anything until it can be agreed upon and wide support can at least be predicted.